# Managing pushtokens in firebase realtime db

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

Our app is used by people in the order of >1M and it does not require any kind of login etc. We use firebase sdk with ionic for get push tokens for the devices. Question is how do we store them efficiently.  Should we use

```
const itemsRef = db.list('tokens');
itemsRef.push({ token:"tokenValue" });
```

The above will keep adding a new node every time a device opens the app. My concern here is avoiding to add same pushToken again. As in the above structure query against a million of nodes to see if push token exists could be a huge performance issue (I think so not sure).

What is the recommendation to deal this? i am feeling query for a pushtoken if it exists could be expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can store a lot of keys under a single node. In fact, I don't think there's a [documented limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). Although I'm quite sure there's a theoretical value at which it stops working, you're unlikely to hit it in a real app. It's just storing some data, so nothing stop you from storing millions of values here.

The tricky bit is getting this data out of the database again. But for example, if you know the exact location of the data you want to read, and the data size that you're reading is reasonable, the limit it quite high again.

It's only when you want to read/query the list of keys that you run into limitations. The common advice here is that you shouldn't query more than a few hundred thousand child nodes, although in the past few years that number seems to have gone up. But querying (or reading) millions of nodes is going to be a performance concern.

> My concern here is avoiding to add same pushToken again.

If you want a value to be unique in the database (no matter if you're using the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore), you should use that value as the key of a node (or the ID of a document in Firestore). In code that'd be:

```
const itemsRef = db.list('tokens');
itemsRef.child("tokenvalue").set(true);
```

Keys are by definition unique within their parent node, so using the push tokens as keys automatically guarantees that you'll only have one child node for each push token.

Comment: Well as these are push tokens so we need to read them on server side in a firebase function. The usecase is there is a articles node. whenever a new article is added by admins, the firebase db create trigger fires and that need to push notification to all the devices. So, there is no need to query for us as it goes to all.  Do, you see any issues in just do a read all using your approach of using token itself as key ?

Comment: I described the limits of the system, precisely to help you answer follow up questions yourself. Reading millions of nodes will be a problem, both for memory usage of the server *and* for the bandwidth you consume. But why did your question say: "As in the above structure query against a million of nodes to see if push token exists" if you don't need to query?

Comment: Sorry to create the confusion. The query part of my question was for the approach i was initially think to make sure pushTokens are unique. Which you answered already.

My 2nd concern was on reading all to send push notifications. So, in that case i just need all tokens from top to bottom under tokens node. So, I asked if there is any suggestions on handling server side of code to read millions push token and use firebase messaging to send to devices.

Comment: As I said, there is a practical limit to how many child nodes you can read at once. I'd recommend sharding the tokens if you needs number beyond that. For example: create a hierarchy where you put each tokens under a parent node that is the same as the first character of that token: `/tokens/0/01231237`, `/tokens/0/047324`/, `/tokens/1/128759`, `/tokens/1/12asd9`, etc. That way you can loop over the (hard-coded)` shard names, and read a slice of the tokens.

Comment: Hi Frank, i did the segmentation as you recommended. However, got a question related to this while i read. so in my firebase function how do i go about reading this in efficient way. If i will do db.ref('/tokens') it will still end up reading entire tree and defeats the purpose. I dont see a way to read only keys of tokens's children and then read each children bucket one by one. Please advise

Comment: If you use the first digit of the token to determine what bucket/shard to put each token in, you can just loop from 0-9 to read each bucket/shard in turn.

Comment: Well first letter of these tokens is not just digit.  It's anything between a-z A-Z  numerals and some special chars like underscore.  So sounds too much to iterate through than simple 0 to 9

Comment: It'd be the same iteration, just over a longer dictionary. I'm not sure how that would make a difference, but either way: if you want all tokens, you will need to read all buckets/shards.